# Aptana Configuration : The interpreter configured does not exist in the filesystem

Tags: python, django, aptana, aptana3

Pretty much all said in the title.
I've updated to the last version of `Aptana`(on Windows), and now my interpreter does not work.
I've recreated the `PYTHONPATH` Variable, deleted and reconfigured the python interpreter in `Aptana`, deleted and recreated it in my project, still not working...

It gives me following error:

```
The interpreter configured does not exist in the filesystem
```

And all kinds of error like :

```
Description Resource        Path        Location    Type
Undefined variable: None    models.py   line 48     PyDev Problem
```

Worst part is, I work on a `django` app. and I can launch it fine, the only problem resides in Aptana.
Any clue?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. :/ It didn't happen until a few days after I'd updated though.

Comment: A lot of people seem to be complaining about this, still there are no statements from Aptana, this is getting very annoying, and counter productive...

Comment: Ok, I'm complaining too.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, tried removing and then re-adding(automatically) the interpreter. No go, same thing.

However, then I tried manually adding it, called it Python27 and put in the path c:\python\python27.exe

It automatically found the right folders and paths it needed like site packages and libs etc. Then the error disappeared!