# Django not detected in Aptana 3.6.0 update

Tags: django, python-2.7, aptana3

Similar to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25311417/3005173)

Updating Aptana to version 3.6.0 breaks Django detection in the Python interpreter.

- Using Django version 1.6.5
- Currently referencing the default python interpreter at "C:\Python27"
- Typing "import django" into the python interpreter in the command line works fine.
- The PyDev Django Project new project wizard does not allow me to create a project with the interpreter selected.
- Reconfiguring the interpreter makes no difference.
- If I manually add "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django" to the PYTHONPATH I can continue the project setup but I get the error message:

> To get started with Django in Pydev, a pre-requisite is that Django is installed in the Python/ Jython/ IronPython interpreter you want to use (so, "import django" must properly work). It seems that the selected interpreter does not have Django available, so, please install Django, reconfigure the interpreter so that Django is recognized and then come back to this wizard.

I can create a django project outside of Aptana and run the dev server from the cmd and everything works just fine.  I also tried using Python Tools for Visual Studio and I created a Django project and everything worked fine as well.

What gives Aptana?

Comment: Just a quick update, I've opened a [bug report](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8294) with Appcelerator about this.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to post this as a potential workaround:

Django is working fine with [Eclipse Luna](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) using the PyDev extension.  Since the IDE's are fairly close to one another in style and configuration, I'm going to call it close enough.